# How to draw a scatter plot with multiple y values for each x value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, visualization

I have data in the following format which I would like to plot using d3:

```
data = [
        { x: 0.2, y: [ 1, 2, 4 ] },
        { x: 0.3, y: [ 2 ] },
        { x: 0.5, y: [ 4, 7, 8, 12, 19 ] }
        { x: 1.4, y: [ 1, 3 ] }
       ]
```

Normally the y-axis values are integers, but here they are arrays, so the following code doesn't work as intended:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.x) })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d.y) })
        .attr("r", 2)
```

Instead of getting multiple circles plotted for each of the values in the array, I only get one.

Other similar questions on this website deal only with data that has a fixed number of y-axis values, so I haven't found a way to modify those solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional D3 answer here would be appending a group for each object and then appending a circle for each `y` value for each group.

However, since you seem to be a D3 beginner (correct me if I'm wrong), I'd suggest to just create a single array of objects, that you can pass to `data`.

There are several ways for doing this, such as:

```
const newData = data.reduce(function(a, c) {
  return a.concat(c.y.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: c.x,
      y: d
    }
  }));
}, []);
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const data = [{
    x: 0.2,
    y: [1, 2, 4]
  },
  {
    x: 0.3,
    y: [2]
  },
  {
    x: 0.5,
    y: [4, 7, 8, 12, 19]
  }, {
    x: 1.4,
    y: [1, 3]
  }
];

const newData = data.reduce(function(a, c) {
  return a.concat(c.y.map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: c.x,
      y: d
    }
  }));
}, []);

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 2])
  .range([0, 300]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 20])
  .range([0, 150]);

const svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(newData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.y)
  })
  .attr("r", 4)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try unwrapping your data array before? That should be easy to process.

```js
data = [{
    x: 0.2,
    y: [1, 2, 4]
  },
  {
    x: 0.3,
    y: [2]
  },
  {
    x: 0.5,
    y: [4, 7, 8, 12, 19],
  },
  {
    x: 1.4,
    y: [1, 3]
  }
];
unwrappedData = [];

for (b in data) {
  var temp = data[b].y.map((foo) => {
    return {
      x: data[b].x,
      y: foo
    }
  })
  unwrappedData = unwrappedData.concat(temp);

}

console.log(unwrappedData);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("margin-top", "58px");

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(unwrappedData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", 2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Also, shouldn't the cx and cy attributes return `d.x` and `d.y` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works but I have chosen the other because it's about five times faster. I thought I'd let you know if you were interested in looking at the performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the grouping solution as mentioned in the first answer:

```
     svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
     .data(data)
     .join("g")
     .selectAll("circle").data(d => d.x.map(y => ({ x: d.x, y })))
   
     .join("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
     })
     .attr("cy", function(d) {
      
        return y(d.y);
     })
     .attr("r", 2)
```